# How can I check if a variable is relative to a number?

Tags: game-maker

I would like to know how to check if a variable is relative to a number in Game Maker.
An Example would be:

```
if variablex += 1  
{  
    DOTHIS
}
```

However this is not possible in Game Maker so I was wondering if there was some sort of equivalent that I could use.

Comment: if (a == b + 1)

Comment: It is unclear what the code is supposed to do, as in other languages, as it currently stands it is an in-place incrementation by one, and a test if it's non-zero. Please elaborate what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks JPtheK9, I feel stupid now because that was so simple xD

Answer (score 0):

This expression that you have in your `IF` is not really an expression. You just add 1 to `variablex` and it should be true always, meaning that `DOTHIS` is ran always.

```
variablex += 1
```

If structure in GameMaker

```
if (<expression>)
{
  <statement>
}
```

Say, you have variable `x` and you need to know if its value is `10`:

```
if (x == 10)
{
  DOTHIS
}
```

To compare `x` with other var increment:

```
if (x == y + 10)
{
  DOTHIS
}
```

I suggest that you read the manual once, to get some idea about programming in general. It's not easy stuff, but certainly nothing that you can't handle.

[GameMaker manual - If statement](http://gamemaker.info/en/manual/401_08_if)

Comment: Katu, I understand what if statements do, if I didn't I wouldn't be writing a game in code. I wanted to check if a variable had an incrementation of +1 rather than re-writing if varaiblex = 1, if variablex = 2 etc.

Comment: Well, your sentence just does not make sense. X is NEVER X + 1. Never, ever.  X can be Y + 1. So, you have to compare X to some other number, like is X == 2, is X greater than 2 and less than 4 -> if(X > 2 && x < 4).

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax of if condition is

```
if (<expression>)
   {
   <statement>
   ...
   <statement>
   }
```

But using **variablex += 1** means **variablex =  variablex+ 1** which is always true.
Condition should always be **variablex==1**